# How do I turn this Bezier thing into a normal mesh that I can edit?

Tags: mesh, bezier-curves

I followed a youtube tutorial to make the handle of this watering can. I had to make a path and a "bezier" circle, I don't really know what that means.

[image]

The outliner looks like this

[image]

I can't actually select the bezier thing or the curve by clicking on them, I have to select them in the Outliner. I'd like to do away with all of that stuff, it has the right shape now, I just want the mesh that you can see in the viewport, so I can reduce the polycount and export it. How do I do this? I tried pressing alt+C a couple of times with those things selected, as I found on the internet, but that didn't work.

Edit: Here's the file: [image]

Comment: If I do that, it just disappears and leaves only the curve

Comment: While i see the NurbsPath (not a beveled one as it seems) and the little circle on the left i believe is the BezierCircle, it is not so easy to find the solution based on just the picture and your description. Would it be possible to upload the blend file, to check it out?

Comment: @RobinBetts I shared it.

Comment: @RobinBetts the workings of a Q&A site fail if you post answers as comments. Perhaps you could frame your solution as an answer and also mention that the OP cannot select the Nurbs Path because they are still in Edit mode.

Comment: I found the same question with some more details and posted an answer there, just to make it possible to find the answer : https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/158738/if-i-convert-a-beziercircle-to-mesh-from-curve-it-just-disappears

Comment: @Merlin.. Thanks.. noted.

Comment: On suggestion from @Merlin, i deleted my answer on the duplicate and re-posted it here to avoid it eventually being deleted. I didn't use the blend file as i did the answer between asking for it and finding the other question with the more details, on which i based the answer. That said, it sure helps with solving a problem if the blend file is posted along with the question, especially if there are certain flags set like disabled selectability for items.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure exactly why, but the handle Nurbs Curve was marked 'Unselectable'. So the first step for me was to hit the little filter funnel at the top of the Outliner, to expose the 'Selectable' toggle switches.

Then, after making it selectable, I could select the handle curve in the 3D view, in Object Mode, and use the Header > Object Menu > Convert to > Mesh.

[image]

You might want to go into the Data > Geometry panels of the both the profile and the path curves to adjust their 'Preview U' settings. Those will determine the resolution of the mesh, after conversion.. it maybe doesn't need to be as high as this, compared to the rest of your model.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! That was very helpful. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

A little explanatory video to help you on your way. Explanation following right after.

[image: nurbspath to mesh]

The BezierCircle is only a means to the end of your object, thus converting it sure does not help, it essentially takes it out from the NurbsPath and makes that one lose the shape you want. Instead you need to convert the NurbsPath to a mesh object. As it says object, it means you find the correlating function under the "Object" menu (only in "Object Mode"), "Convert To" and then "Mesh from Curve/Meta/Surf/Text". All that is shown in the little video/gif above. Just wrote it out to make it easier to follow. The resulting details of the mesh then depend on the settings in your nurbspath, so before you convert it, it's a good idea to adjust the settings a bit for less work with the mesh afterwards.

Comment: Thank you very much you guys! That was very helpful.