# If I convert a BezierCircle to mesh from curve, it just disappears

Tags: mesh, bezier-curves

This is the curve I want to turn into a mesh:
[image]

This is what the outliner looks like:
[image]

Someone on this forum told me to select the BezierCircle, go to Object>Convert to>Mesh from curve

But if I do that, it looks like this:
[image]

I've messed around with this thing for literal hours, and I just can't figure it out. All I want is for Blender to turn that handle, into a mesh which I can edit like any other mesh.

This information may also be needed:
[image]

Comment: which curve are you converting the one for the handle or the profile curve that is selected in your screenshot?

Comment: Hi @Dereck.  Just a point to note, this is not a forum, it is a Q'n'A site. This question seems like an extension to your previous one (which has no answers).  I don't wish to discourage you, but it does seem strange.

Comment: You have to convert the Nurbs Path, not the Bezier Circle.

Comment: I'm starting to think this is a bug, when I googled it I came on a page that reported a bug similar to this. But I feel like by now more people should've noticed, so it might just be me. Converting the Nurbs Path makes no sense to me, but I did try, and Blender doesn't let you do it (the option is greyed out).

Comment: @FFeller an answer would be more constructive to the site mechanics than a comment.

Answer (score 2):

> Someone on this forum told me to select the BezierCircle, go to Object>Convert to>Mesh from curve

This would appear to be poor interpretation of advice, instead you should select your "Nurbs Path" object then Object -> Convert to -> Mesh from Curve.

If you are running the latest version of blender ( 2.81 ), then you could alterenatively right click the object and select "Convert to Mesh".

Either way this question is a [duplicate of your previous question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/158727/how-do-i-turn-this-bezier-thing-into-a-normal-mesh-that-i-can-edit) and I am only providing this answer to prevent further duplicates.

Comment: Sorry, didn't realize there was a duplicate here ..

Comment: @RobinBetts, not at all, you provided a good and annotatedd answer in the right place.  I was just trying to stem the tide of duplicate answers.  Evidently I failed, as Xylvier has erroneously decided to answer here.  If this question is closed as a duplicate then your answer will still exist.